# Highstock set XAxis extreme without data

Tags: highcharts

I have Highstock with default data for each year from 2001 to 2009 as shown in below JSFiddle:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mzfoavc8/)

Now on button click event I want to increase the xAxis extreme to year 2020 even though there is no data available.

I am trying to set extreme by following code:

```
var newDate = new Date(2019, 03, 23).getTime();
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(new Date(2000, 1, 1).getTime(), newDate, true);
```

But its not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Highcharts API we can read:

> **ordinal: boolean**
>
> In an ordinal axis, the points are equally spaced in the chart regardless of the actual time or x distance between them. This means that missing data periods (e.g. nights or weekends for a stock chart) will not take up space in the chart. Having ordinal: false will show any gaps created by the gapSize setting proportionate to their duration.
>
> In stock charts the X axis is ordinal by default, unless the boost module is used and at least one of the series' data length exceeds the boostThreshold.
>   Defaults to true.

So, you need to disable the `ordinal` option:

```
xAxis: {
    ordinal: false
},
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/fzo7ahg0/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for,

Comment: with this change I am able to set extreme but now it is adding gaps between two data points when there is no data or weekend. Is there any work around for this ?

Comment: Hi @confusedDeveloper, Instead of setting the extremes, you can add invisible series: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6qut5j4e/